# Elastic Beanstalk Application Can't Connect to Database but Server Can

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I have an Elastic Beanstalk application that can't connect to the database but the server it's running on can connect to the database just fine.

When I try to deploy my elastic beanstalk application, it gives me a database error `Access Denied` (the deploy process needs to connect to the database in order to run migrations.  My database is on RDS.  I have the environment variables for the database configured in the environment.  I have the security groups set up to allow the environment servers to connect to RDS.  When I ssh into the server, I can open a database connection through the database terminal to the database.  It's only the application that can't connect.  What is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is non-alphanumeric characters in the database password.  In this case, the particular culprit is "$".  Changing the database password to be purely alphanumeric solves it.

Elastic beanstalk environment variables are passed to your application through a shell script that it generates.  If you have a dollar sign in your password, Linux will interpret this as a shell variable embedded in the password and will ignore anything after the dollar sign in the password.